# Python Import a library inside a function for multi-threading

Tags: python, multithreading, function, global

I have a library that uses quite a few global variables, that I'd like to use in a multi-threaded application, however what I'd like to know is if I import the library inside a function, will the library's global variables etc. be separate copies, so that they don't corrupt each other?

Comment: If they're constants, does it matter? If they're actual global variables, then you should avoid that.

Comment: No they're proper global variables, looks like I'll have to rewrite some of it. Thanks Anyway.

Comment: I would argue that global variables are never proper! ;o)

Answer (score 1):

No. There will only be a single instance of the 'global' variables (presumably defined at the top level of the module).

A module is only ever imported once, importing it a second time simply adds it to the appropriate namespace.

Comment: Damn, I knew that was going to be too easy. Ohh well, time to go through the code, and see how much can be re-written.

Answer (score 1):

No. Python has **Module Scope** here whereby the *global* variables you have defined in that module if mutated by other threads without locking will have unpredictable behaviour.

I would refactor your code into a set of objects with remove the use of globals and possibly also implement locking if you intend  to share the same objects.

Comment: Thanks James, it was for a quick and dirty test, that'll only probably run a couple of times, was hoping not to have to rewrite too much. I'll have a rethink.